# Finding minimum in outputs of a forloop

Tags: python, printing, minimum

How can we find minimum value in output of a loop without creating a list?

```
for i in range(1,5):
    R1=np.random.uniform(0,10,i)
    def L():        
        d=R1**2
        return d
    print("i= ",i, min(L()))
```

this code gives minimum for each `i`:

```
i=1, 0.00477514033271
i=2, 5.65882743189
i=3, 0.783497908243
i=4, 0.224239938297
```

but the minimum value of the whole outputs is: `0.00477514033271`

Thank yo for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a textbook problem (If I understood your question correctly).

```
import numpy as np

# variable to keep track of the minimum seen so far
temp = 1e10 # a big big big value
for i in range(1,5):
    R1=np.random.uniform(0,10,i)
    def L():
        d=R1**2
        return d
    m = min(L())
    if m < temp:
        temp = m
    print("i= ",i, min(L()))

print ("Min is :", temp)
```